# Deploy and schedule console application in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service

I got a web scraping tool developed using C# console application and Selenium Chrome driver.

Is there an option to deploy and schedule to run daily in Azure platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an option to deploy and schedule to run daily in Azure
>   platform?

Yes. You can deploy your console application project to a web App service as an **Azure Webjob**.If you're unfamiliar with Azure Webjob, you can see details in [this wiki](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki). But I'm not sure whether your application can still work well, because it depends on your application itself and running environment sometimes.

**You can use Visual Studio to deploy it**. You can follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs) to achieve that.

If you have already created a Webjob and want deploy it to Azure, you can refer to [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/03/07/how-to-deploy-a-net-core-console-application-to-azure-webjob/).

**Schedule the Webjob:**

When you deploy the Webjob, you can [use CRON to schedule your Webjob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs#CreateScheduledCRON).

Comment: Thank a lot Wayne Yang, Let me try this out.

Comment: OK, If you have any process or issue, don't be shy to let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Very kind of you. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi,@Gunarathinam , sorry for the bad answer and I have edited it now. you can use CRON to scedule your Webjob.

Comment: Hi Wayne, Thanks for the update. I can able to configure and run the job using Webjobs, but I couldn't able to run my web scrapping logic, as remote connections are not allowed. Is there any alternative in Azure stack?

Comment: Hi, @Gunarathinam , I'm not familiar with Azure Stack. If you want to ask another question which relates to Azure stack, you can post a new question in Stack Overflow. Also, if this answer is helpful to you , please mark it as an answer , so that we can help more people. Thanks!